Gradle Build Failing After Updating React Native from 0.67.3 to 0.75.4
Question:
I have a React Native project that was running on version 0.67.3. I recently updated it to 0.75.4 following the guidelines provided by the React Native upgrade helper. After running npm install, it worked fine. However, when I tried to build the project with the following commands:
./gradlew clear
./gradlew build

The ./gradlew clear command failed with the following errors:
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'MyProject/android/app/build.gradle' line: 84

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not read script 'MyProject/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle' as it does not exist.

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

Below is my android/build.gradle configuration:
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.20"
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        exclusiveContent {
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
       }
    }
}

And here’s my gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

The errors indicate that:

react.gradle cannot be found in MyProject/node_modules/react-native.
compileSdkVersion is not specified in the build.gradle file, though I’ve defined it as 33.

My questions:

Should I update my Gradle version, Kotlin version, or SDK versions (buildToolsVersion, minSdkVersion, compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, ndkVersion)?
Is there anything else I need to configure in the project after upgrading React Native?
How can I resolve the missing react.gradle file issue?

I'm new to React Native, so any guidance on how to fix these issues would be greatly appreciated!
